# MSP430G2553 Reading from ADC10 Temperature with Button ISR

Tags: adc, temperature, interrupts, msp430

This is my lab assignment. When I press the button, the red LED toggles on and off. But, I can't seem to read anything from it. Also, there's an empty loop in the code, but I don't know what to insert there, in order to read the temperature. Also, this code was a template before, I filled out all of it except that while loop. What can I write there?

```
#include "msp430g2553.h"
#define RED BIT0
long Sample;
long i=0;

void main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Stop WatchDog Timer

    // Button
    P1DIR &= ~BIT3; // P1.3 (push button) as input, 0 input
    P1OUT |= BIT3;
    P1REN |= BIT3; // Enable P1.3 (push button) resistor
    P1SEL &= ~BIT3; // Select P1.3 (push button), 0 selects
    P1IE |= BIT3; // Port 1 Interrupt Enable P1.3 (Push Button)
    P1IFG &= ~BIT3; // Clear Interrupt Flag P1.3
    P1IES |= BIT3; // P1.3 Lo/Hi edge

    // Led
    P1DIR |= BIT0; // RED LED as output
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0; // LED off

    BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ; // Set range
    DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ; // Set DCO step + modulation
    BCSCTL2 |= SELM_0 + DIVM_3; // MCLK = DCO/8 These bits select the MCLK source

    ADC10CTL1 = INCH_10 + ADC10DIV_7; // Temp Sensor ADC10CLK/8
    ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 + ADC10SHT_2 + REFON + REFOUT + ADC10ON; //+ ADC10IE; //+ ADC10IE-->Int EnablE;
    // Ref voltage/Sample&Hold Time
    // Ref Generator ON/ADC10 ON

    _BIS_SR(LPM0_bits + GIE); // LPM0 General CPU Interrupts Enabled
    while(1) i++; { // Execute some useful computation

    }
    }

#pragma vector=PORT1_VECTOR // ISR for Button ADC10 operation
__interrupt void Port_1 (void) {
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC; // ADC sampling and conversion start
    Sample = ADC10MEM; // Read ADC sample
    P1OUT ^= BIT0; // Toggle Red LED state
    P1IFG &= ~BIT3; // P1.3 Interrupt Flag cleared
    _BIC_SR(LPM0_EXIT); // Exit LPM0
    }
```

Comment: The `while(1)` superloop is a key concept in understanding how bare-metal embedded systems operate. Whatever tasks need to be serviced periodically by the MCU will reside in the superloop (such as checking temperature via the ADC). The format inside the superloop will be along the lines of: `1) read temperature, 2) delay a certain amount of time, 3) repeat.`

Comment: How do I read the temperature though? That was my question. I wrote Sample = ADC10MEM inside the loop but nothing happened.

Comment: Ah I see what you're doing, I thought that it was missing the code to read an ADC value. I'm unsure why it's not working, sorry.